# How do I know if I can trust a DNS service

Tags: dns

How can I decide if I could trust a given DNS service as a user?

For example I have just seen [DNS-Watch](https://dns.watch/why) which tells me that it is 
secure and that they don't log anything.

How can I decide if the claims about security and privacy are reliable?

Answer (score 2):

Trust is a tricky issue. How does one trust a person in real-life: Either one has already positive experiences with this person or because one trusts others which say that this person is trust-worthy too. Sometimes one also trust a person because of their appearance, like being dressed in a suite and a tie vs. a t-shirt and ripped jeans. But appearance alone can easily be faked.

As for DNS-Watch: they seem to try looking trustworthy by appearance. There are many nice buzzwords like Net Neutrality, Privacy or Uncensored on the page but there is nothing which makes verifying such claims possible. There are no well known and trusted references. Even quite contrary: the [impress](https://iamonsys.com/imprint/) shows that the service is provided by a company which does among others social media management and movie based advertisement, areas which are not typically associated with privacy.

That said, I have not enough information to actually decide if the service is trust-worthy or not. But currently it looks more suspicious than trustworthy to me. If the provider really offers all these nice things it might be a good idea to make it possible for others to verify these claims. Or being publicly and verifiable endorsed by some well-known privacy focused organization might also help to establish trust.